# Video Quality Measurement Framework/Tool for Android

Tags: android, video, frameworks, video-streaming, videoquality

I'm in search of **Tool/Framework** to measure the video Quality. Basically I want to compare the transmitted and received video file. The video file will be transmitted from Network and will be played on Android phone.
(Basic Video comparison is OK)
I went across many video framework tools on internet but could not find a convincing answer.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right you want a tool to get info of a video and manipulate it.

You can use FFmpeg library for it.

1. getting video information use command

   ffmpeg -i
2. for other manipulations follow the documentation
   https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

here is the working android port of ffmpeg

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your suggestion. I'm aware of FFmpeg. But that is not what I'm actually looking for. I'm interested in framework designed  (which will have for ex : ffmpeg, opencv , gstreamer ) for video comparison. Something like this http://enchufa2.github.io/video-tester/index.html